# Passing shell variable to a mktime awk command

Tags: shell

Can you help me with this script ?

```
#!/bin/bash
data=`date '+%Y %m %d'`
data2=" 7 0 0"
string=$data$data2
awk -v str=$string '{print mktime("str");}'
```

I´m getting this output:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: cannot open file `09' for reading (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: This one command can replace your script: `date -d "7:00" +%s`, assuming you have GNU date.

Answer (score 2):

You should not quote `str` inside awk otherwise it is treated as a literal string. You must also quote the shell variables properly.

```
#!/bin/bash

data=$(date '+%Y %m %d')
data2=" 7 0 0"
string="$data$data2"

awk -v str="$string" 'BEGIN {print mktime(str)}'
```

Comment: @user3178903, you **must** use quotes here: `-v str="$string"`

Comment: Can you replace the first 3 lines with string=$(date '+%Y %m %d 07 00 00') ? And I thought mktime() required the date with leading zeroes on the hours, i.e. 07 00 00 rather than 7 0 0? And the whole things hangs my iMac running OSX with awk version 20070501? Any offers?

Comment: @MarkSetchell, as you've discovered, you do no *require* the leading zero for elements of the mktime datespec.

Comment: @MarkSetchell: The hang is likely due to AWK waiting for input... there should be a `;exit` after the mktime in the BEGIN block, otherwise awk waits for input from stdin...

Answer (score 0):

@anubhava has the right answer. Here's why: after variable substitution, the shell sees this line in your code:

```
awk -v str=2014 01 09 7 0 0 '{print mktime("str");}'
```

So, you're passing "2014" as the "str" variable, your awk script is "01" (which is a valid awk program that will print every line), and passing the file arguments "09", "7", ...  Hence the error "cannot open file `09' for reading"

Lesson: in shell scripting, unless you know when not to, **always** quote your `"$variables"`.

Comment: #!/bin/bash set -x data=`date '+%Y %m %d'` data2=" 7 0 0" string="$data$data2" awk -v str=$string '{print mktime(str);}'  awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: cannot open file `09' for reading (No such file or directory)

Comment: Why are you ignoring my advice: `-v str="$string"` -- **with the quotes**

Answer (score 0):

You want this:

```
#!/bin/bash
data="`date '+%Y %m %d'`"
data2=" 7 0 0"
string="$data$data2"
awk -v str="$string" 'BEGIN {print mktime(str);exit;}'
```

Another alternative for the `awk` line is: (This has the advantage of working on older `awk` versions that lack the `-v` option, like Solaris 10 `/usr/bin/awk` (They tend to miss `mktime` though))

```
awk "BEGIN {print mktime(\"$string\");exit;}"
```

The BEGIN block is needed to make `awk` run the code at startup and not for every input line.

The `exit` is needed to make it quit before it waits for input. (It seems to work without it on GAWK)

The quotes are needed to pass the variable as a single entry... [This overview of shell quoting](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sh.html#uh-6) is important reading for anyone attempting shell scripting...

The quotes in the `awk` code needs to be left out to get awk to use the variable `str` and not the string `str`.

You likely also want to replace the backticks (``) with `$()`, it is much easier to read in complicated, nested cases and supported in all modern shells (It seems like it might be in the POSIX standard, I haven't checked though...).. (It doesn't affect the code in this case though)

Comment: (Since most stuff, except the `exit` was answered already by other people, I made it community wiki...)